# Specify LoaderOptimization's for Windows Services

Tags: c#, windows-services, service

How do we specify LoaderOptimizations when we are building a Windows Service, we don't have our "Main" method as we would otherwise use

In other words, when we have a simple console application we can:

```
[LoaderOptimization(LoaderOptimization.MultiDomainHost)] 
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
}
```

but for a Service, we implement the ServiceBase class and therefore don't have the main method, instead we have an

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
}
```

But I am guessing that putting the attribute on that method won't have the same effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will still have a Main method for a Windows Service.  It will typically be where you call [ServiceBase.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.run.aspx).  The Visual Studio template for a Windows Service project will generate a class called Program that looks something like this and includes the Main() method:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new Service1() 
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
}
```

You should be able to add an attribute to the Main() method there.

Comment: Currently sitting here banging my head against the wall repeating the word "Doh"... 

Guess it is the heat that is getting to us here, we are no more than 3 who knew it but clearly forgotten it as well...

But Thank you very much for the help >.<...